# Upgrading Flash AS3 project to CS5 and using Flash Builder 4 as IDE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe

I have been working for quite some time with the Flex Builder (3) as the development IDE,
and used Flash CS3 to compile my flp file (all the actionscript I wrote in the Flex Builder).
I don't use any of the Flex components. Pure AS3 and FLA for symbols.

I want to upgrade to CS5, and I read that there is a new Flash builder IDE so I thought I'll give it a try. But In the Flash builder I see that they have tighten the Flex SDK relation (which is kinda stupid since they change the name from Flex to Flash?) so I am a bit stuck with how to migrate my project.

Furthermore, is there a way to download the Flash 10 compiler/SDK or whatever to make it compile from the Flash builder, and not use Flash CS5 for it?

Thanks a lot.
Chen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pure AS3 projects with the FlashBuilder IDE without worrying about the Flex framework. Simply create a new Actionscript project. You can then compile your project in FlashBuilder and strictly use CS5 for your graphic assets.

In order to migrate your project , you only need to add your classes folder to your project source library.

With Flash CS5 , export a SWC and add it to the project's library path. All this is accessible via your project Properties.

From that point on, you should be able to access both your project classes and your symbols by declaring your variables with the relevant classes.

---

Edit

Start simply, first create a new Actionscript project in FlashBuilder.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7ff7.html

After you successfully created a project and tested it, you can then add the code from Login.swf.

If you've been using a Document Class, you could create an instance of that class and add it to the stage, you could also simply copy the code in your Main class.

If Login.swf doesn't use any graphical assets, you should be good to go, without the need to load any SWCs.

You could also refactor your code so that each concern is encapsulated within its own class. For instance, if Login.swf serves as user login and loads a bunch of SWFs, it may be a good idea to create a Login class and an AssetsLoader class.

Comment: Hi, My project contains an entry point (Login.swf) that loads 26 more swfs. No SWCs for me. I am still a bit confused about how to compile the project.

Comment: Plus when I try to debug the project using FB4 it says:  This project does not contain any applications. Create an application file by selecting File > New > MXML Application or select an existing MXML file and set it as an application file.